# Celsius/Fahrenheit converter

Tags: javascript, converters, temperature

There seems to be a problem in the function code, as anything after the functions won't run.

I tested it by giving the the `conversion` variables a value in the 2 functions and returning the value. It worked then.

```
function celsius(input) { /*convert to Celsius*/

    var conversion = 5;
    /*conversion = (5.0 / 9.0) * (input – 32);*/

    return conversion;
}
```

Here's the actual code. Nothing happens when I run it. Do I have to use parseFloat in the functions?

```
function celsius(input) { /*convert to Celsius*/

    var conversion;
    conversion = (5.0 / 9.0) * (input – 32);

    return conversion;
}

function fahrenheit(input) { /*convert to Fahrenheit*/

    var conversion;
    conversion = (9.0 / 5.0) * (input + 32);

    return conversion;
}

var temp; /*temperature that will be converted*/
temp = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a temperature to convert"));
var converter; /*type of conversion needed*/
converter = prompt("Enter 'c' to convert to Celsius or 'f' for Fahrenheit ");
converter = converter.toLowerCase();

if (converter == 'c') {
    alert(celsius(temp));
} else if (converter == 'f') {
    alert(fahrenheit(temp));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. You're minus symbol is wrong, it's – and it should be -. What a bug...

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate the script working

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/gocajisite/1/edit

Cheers! And happy scripting!

Comment: Wow. What a bug indeed. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome mate, that's why there is Stackoverflow, to help everyone out!